# Firefox XUL OnTabSwitchEvent

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, addeventlistener

I am using a file with the ending uc.js (in Firefox chrome directory). When a website is completely loaded a msgbox "ReadystateComplete" should appear, and when clicking a tab a msgbox "TabSelected" should appear. -How can I do this ?

```
gBrowser.tabContainer.addEventListener('load', function load(event) {
window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
var urlString = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/';
if (gBrowser.currentURI.spec.startsWith(urlString)) {alert('ReadystateComplete')};
}, false);
gBrowser.tabContainer.addEventListener('TabSelect', function() {
var urlString = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/';
if (gBrowser.currentURI.spec.startsWith(urlString)) {alert('TabSelected')}
```

Comment: We're going to need a reasonably complete [mcve] in order to duplicate this (e.g. where do you define `window`). You're going to need to tell us if you are testing with, or without, multiprocess active (e.g. I'm not sure if the `load` event fires on the `tabContainer` when running multiprocess), etc. You should probably first test with multiprocess disabled, just to check if your issue is wrt. using multiprocess.

Comment: What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to install and use the extension?

Comment: Just to be sure you are aware: Do you know that all types of extensions, other than WebExtensions are deprecated and will be removed/disabled in Firefox 57 (scheduled for 2017-11-14)? Thus, any new development should *really* use WebExtensions, if at all possible.